# Ошибка redis сервера: Failed to connect to redis: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: debian, redis

Все чаще и чаще в логе redis сервера ошибка:

> Failed to connect to redis: Cannot assign requested address

Как обнаружить причину возникновения?

redis 4.0.6, debian 9.3

Comment: скорее всего, что вы не правильно указываете хост для подключения. Как происходит подключение? удаленный хост с открытым портом? или через ssh тунель?

Comment: подключение работает. ошибка возникает не постоянно. подключение открытое ip/порт. банальный тест через "ab" не встречает эту ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение**

На сервере клиенте, который подключается к redis серверу, было слишком много соединений в статусе `TIME-WAIT`, более 60к.

Выяснить текущее количество соединений с группировкой по статусам:

`ss -tan | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

Помогло добавление на сервере клиенте:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

В конфиге `/etc/sysctl.conf`

После чего `sysctl -p` для применения изменений.

Стоит учитываться, что лимит портов может быть и на самом redis сервере. Проверяется и лечится точно так же.